# Add tag [macos], change [mac-os-x] to be its synonym

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[mac-os-x](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-x) should be renamed to [macos](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos). The brand [*Mac OS X*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X#macOS) was changed to macOS alongside the announcement and release of macOS Sierra in 2016. To reflect this, we should change the tag to [macos](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos), but keep [mac-os-x](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-x) as a synonym that will automatically change to [macos](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) when used.