# Create tag [synonym-request] for UX Meta

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, meta

It's common on meta SE sites to have a tag named [synonym-request](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonym-request). For an example, see [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonym-request).

> A request to add one tag as the synonym of another tag. Please be specific about which tag should be a synonym of which. Bidirectional synonyms and cycles are implicitly disallowed, so suggest wisely.

<sup>[Info from Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonym-request/info)</sup>

Since I have less than 300 reputation, I cannot create this, but I needed it with [my latest meta question](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3230/57304).

Comment: We have [tag:tag-synonyms] already, so are you suggesting renaming this one, or adding a brand new tag? And are there any questions tagged [tag-synonym] that wouldn't also be suitable for [tag:synonym-request]? And vica-versa - are there any synonym-request posts that wouldn't require [tag:tag-synonyms]?

Comment: @JonW According to [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-synonyms/info): "This tag is for questions about tag synonyms (how they work, who can create them, etc). Use [tag:synonym-request] for tag synonym requests."